# How to know the encoding of a .php file

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Whenever we create a file, you can choose the type of coding in different text editors.

My question is, when using php, make reading a file, but the file is not specified in bytes if it is (UTF8, ISO 8859-1, ANSI ...).

But I realize that there are "bits" at the end of that file because the php returns the last STRING with 0.
string '' (length = 0)

```
<?php 
    $leitor = fopen('2.php','rb');
    while(!feof($leitor)){
        var_dump(fread($leitor, 1));
    }
    fclose($leitor);
?>
```

[image]

I believe that this part should contain the type of encoding (UTF-8, ANSI ...)

1) Where is informed on the type of file encoding (UTF8 - 000001, ANSI - 000011)?

2) How do I read "bits" with php actually want to read these last bits that are represented by:

string '' (length = 0)

Because I can do it with the bytes:

```
function BinString2BitSequence1($mystring) {    
    $result = "";
    $end = strlen($mystring);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $end; $i++){  
        $result .= str_pad(decbin(ord($mystring[$i])), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: "ANSI" isn't an encoding. I have no idea what you mean by "bits at the end of that file".

Comment: Hello, I added an image above to show what I'm saying. ATT

Comment: I don't see any "bits" there but I can't explain your output either. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/fread), the last `fread` call should have returned `FALSE`, not `''`.

Comment: But of course, that one file containing the byte "a" is a file encoded in UTF-8 without BOM?

Comment: Yes, but it's also ISO-8859-1 and ASCII. Basically, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 are supersets of ASCII, so any valid ASCII file is valid in those two, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that this part should contain the type of encoding (UTF-8, ANSI ...)

You are incorrect. The empty string you're reading at the end of your file is just that: an empty string. It contains no information.

The `feof()` function only returns true *after* a read has already reached the end of the file; as such, it's often not useful. Instead, consider something like:

```
while (strlen($str = fread($fh, 1)) > 0) {
   ...
}
```

With regard to text encodings, the encoding used for a file is not stored anywhere in the file. It must be inferred by the application. In some cases (e.g, UTF-8 with BOM), this can be detected reliably; in other cases, it may be ambiguous.

Comment: Got it. So I look for a certain "bytes" to determine the type of coding! Ex: `有`
`string 'æ' (length=1)
 string 'œ' (length=1)
 string '‰' (length=1)`

ATT

Comment: You need to know the encoding before you try to make sense of data. You can only make good guesses which might be wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Here you have it [take a look at this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) 
This function will output encoding based on string just pass your whole text

Comment: 1) Your link isn't clickable because you explicitly marked it as code for some reason. 2) Your link used to go to the Portuguese version of the manual (but you already fixed that). 3) Why the heck do you have a code block containing `**Flies away**` in your answer? 4) The documentation you linked to doesn't actually explain what the function does ... 5) ... but it seems to guess at encodings. That's not very useful. 6) I don't see what any of this has to do with OP's question about "bits at the end" of some file.